# traefik hostname works for web apps but not for mongodb

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm running a mongo instance with docker-compose and traefik.

```
myapp-mongo:
  build: ../images/myapp-mongo
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
  labels:
    - "traefik.ports=27017,27018"
    - "traefik.backend=myapp-mongo"
    - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:myapp-mongo.docker.localhost"
  networks:
    - development
  environment:
    - MONGO_USER=${MONGO_USER}
    - MONGO_PASSWD=${MONGO_PASSWD}
    - MONGO_AUTHDB=${MONGO_AUTHDB}
```

Mongo is running fine and I can connect using `127.0.0.1` from my Mac.

The problem is that I can't connect using hostname `myapp-mongo.docker.localhost`. It only works using IP 127.0.0.1.

Trying to ping the IP 127.0.0.1 responds ok, but trying to ping the hostname doesn't work.

I've already added `127.0.0.1 proxy.docker.localhost` into `/etc/hosts` to get traefik working.

All other web apps has hostnames working fine like eg `myapp.docker.localhost`. This problem is only happening with this mongodb container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because Træfik is HTTP proxy and so will only support HTTP/HTTPS connections.

Comment: Some supporting evidence for your answer from traefik's github account: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/10 *note that the feature request highlights that it's HTTP(S) only at time of posting this comment (with no linked PR's, actions or action items)

Comment: traefik is no longer just a http proxy

Answer (score 1):

I believe @bpatel is right (see comment I left on his answer with link to github conversation) Traefik at the time of writing only supports HTTP/HTTPS.

### Solution using native docker networks

However, you can get around this issue! Since you are using docker, you can work around by using the container name in your code (assuming mongo and your mongo accessing code are both running in containers on a shared docker network. This will be the case if the containers are spun up with `docker-compose`). Run the following to see if your containers are linked up correctly:

1. run `docker ps` to get your container names running (under the `NAMES` column)
2. run `docker network ls` to see your network names
3. run `docker network inspect <target_network_name>` to verify your containers from step 1 are on the same network.

I run docker-compose from three separate compose files, so you should be able to cover most cases from the following (apologies for any syntax errors, the following are stripped down code examples):

### Entire docker-compose file that that starts up traefik (under directory name 'proxy')

```
version: '2'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command: --web --docker --docker.domain=docker.localhost --logLevel=DEBUG
    networks:
      - webgateway
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /dev/null:/traefik.toml
networks:
  webgateway:
    driver: bridge
```

### snippet from my docker-compose file that spins up mongo

```
version: '2'
services:
  database:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - web
networks:
  web:
    external:
      name: proxy_webgateway
```

### snippet from docker-compose that has mongo accessing code

```
version: '2'
services:
  topicOntologyBuilder:
    image: topic-ontology-builder
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=topicOntologyBuilder"
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:topic-ontology.docker.localhost"
    networks:
      - web
    volumes:
      - ./:/home
networks:
  web:
    external:
      name: proxy_webgateway
```

### Connection in Code

Not certain what language you're using, this is what the following js code looked like for me to connect to mongo (inside that 'topicOntologyBuilder` container, while using traefik as the proxy (again, this works because we're making the most of docker networks):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://<MONGO_CONTAINER_NAME>/<DB_NAME>', function(err, db) {
    //insert code here to interact with mongo
})
```

### Why this works

This works because docker does some clever DNS stuff within the containers so that each container knows the IP of other containers, by looking it up in their DNS entry, by the container names

### Extra intel

If your containers are on separate computers/vm's, you'll probably want to play around with a service discovery tool (Consul plays well with Traefik) or do something fancy with a [docker network overlay](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/#create-the-overlay-network) which is specific for containers in a cluster.

If using raw docker networks, you can assign container aliases (this doesn't work with Traefik though, or at least it didn't a couple months back).